# json разбор ответа

Tags: python, json, словари

Подскажите, как добраться до нужных данных:

```py
import requests        
        
params = dict(email="demo@saures.ru", password="demo")
url = 'https://api.saures.ru/1.0/login'
res = requests.post(url, params)
result = json.loads(res.text)
print(result)
```

На выходе в ответе сервера:

```
{'status': 'ok', 'errors': [], 'data': {'sid': '559faac6-f69f-44e3-8e99-a3d087afd6cd', 'role': 1, 'api': 1, 'telegram': True}}
```

Как из ответа получить, например, sid или role?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас в `result` - словарь, обрабатывайте его соответственно:

```
sid = result['data']['sid']
role = result['data']['role']

status = result['status']
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете воспользоваться готовой библиотекой на Python для Saures API https://github.com/adolfaka/pysaures